# Why Do We Need const methods?

Tags: c++

class function const is used to tell the compiler that a class function will not change a member variable. Thus, a constant object of that type can safely call it. Below is a simple example.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class X {
private:
  int a{1};

public:
  void PrintA() const {
    cout << a << "\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  const X x;
  x.PrintA();
}
```

We tell the compiler that #PrintA is const, so constant objects can safely call it. However, it seems that the compiler is actually smart enough to detect that a function is read-only or not, independent of the const keyword. If I add an `a=10` in the above code like so

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class X {
private:
  int a{1};

public:
  void PrintA() const {
    cout << a << "\n";
    a = 10;
  }
};

int main() {
  const X x;
  x.PrintA();
}
```

I get

```
exp.cpp: In member function ‘void X::PrintA() const’:
exp.cpp:11:9: error: assignment of member ‘X::a’ in read-only object
     a = 10;
```

In other words, the const key-word can't trick the compiler into allowing the mutation of a constant object. So my question is, why do developers need to declare a method const? It seems like, even without that hint, the compiler distinguishes read-only and non-read-only methods, so can properly catch cases of attempts to mutate constant objects.

Comment: So that you can call them on `const` objects. If the word `const` wasn't in the declaration of `PrintA()` you wouldn't have got that error message. 'The const key-word can't trick the compiler into allowing the mutation of a constant object' is meaningess. It isn't meant to do that. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Even if the compiler knows, how am I supposed to know when I'm reading your code? Also, the compiler might not have access to the definition of the function in the current translation unit. One of the main points of imposing restrictions is to make it easier for other to understand your code and make sure it doesn't break.

Comment: The `const` key word means that you can not change the logical state of an object. That does not mean you can not change the state of the object. There are other tricks that allow you to change the state of the object as long as you don't change its logical state (You probably have not come across the `mutable` keyword yet. It will be comming to a class near you soon). :-)

Comment: Const also says you intend it to not change state.  Auto detection doesn't know what you intend.

Comment: const protects us from ourselves. It catches mistakes at compile time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a hint -- it's part of the interface of the method. If you remove the const, the error in PrintA will go away and you'll get an error in main instead. You need const for the same reason you need public and private -- to define the interface you want. The compiler will then check to make sure you don't violate that interface you've declared.

Comment: I understand. If an interface didn't declare its methods as const or not, a user of the interface wouldn't be able to tell if their constant object is permitted to use its method or not. And further, even if a method is read-only at one point in time (so a developer uses it on a constant object), without the promise of "const", the implementer of the class may suddenly change the method to be mutating, breaking the user's code.
So as you say, it's an interface for developers to make promises about the nature of the method.

Answer (score 2):

> the compiler distinguishes read-only and non-read-only methods

First consider how easily the compiler can do this with the `const` designation as it exists today.

- To determine if the implementation of `PrintA` obeys the rules, the compiler only needs to look at that implementation.
- To determine if `x.PrintA();` is valid for `const X x;` it only needs the declaration of `PrintA`.

Now imagine if we didn't have function-level `const`

- To determine if the implementation of `PrintA` obeys the rules, the compiler has to determine if it's not acting read-only and then scan across your entire program to find if it ever gets called on a `const` object.

I'm sure that would massively bloat the link time of large programs.

But then a significant concern are `virtual` functions. Imagine one derived class overrides with a read-only implementation, but then a different derived class overrides with a non-read-only implementation. Then if such a method is called on a `const` object, what is the compiler to do since it may not be able to determine at compile-time which implementation is going to be called? Would we just have to rule out virtuals from ever being possible to call on const objects? That would be unfortunately limiting.

Furthermore, this idea wouldn't work when callers vs implementations are separated across DLL boundaries (even for non-virtual functions), since those are only connected together at run-time.

So overall it just seems more difficult/problematic for us the have the ability to declare const objects if we were to leave it to the compiler to have to figure out if methods are implemented in a const way or not.